# How to create Checkbox without submit button in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

How to create a checkbox for the user without the user needing to submit it?

```
[] apple
[] grapes
[] oranges
[] mangoes
```

as soon as the user selects apples,grapes, oranges the SAME page must reload multiple times and say 
"apples","grapes","oranges" etc

..................
Edit

Actually, I need to pass the variables with values as apple grapes mangoes etc
i.e 
if you are on a page www.abc.com/happy.php
after you select apple,grapes etc
the page url should display www.abc.com/happy.php&selection=apple_grapes etc

hope it makes sense.

Comment: Whatever happened to the mangoes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only will need some `javascript` on your `checkboxes`

```
<div id="container"></div>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return writeTo(this)" name="check_list" value="Appel">Apple<br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return writeTo(this)" name="check_list" value="Grape">Grape<br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return writeTo(this)" name="check_list" value="Orange">Orange<br>
```

And you will have this `Javascript`:

```
function writeTo(object) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  if (object.checked) {
     container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + "Added " + object.value + " <br />";   
  } else {
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + "Removed " + object.value + " <br />";   
  }
}
```

This code will write to your `HTML` `element` (`id`=container) **"Added [fruit]"** every time you `check` the fruit. If you `uncheck` it, it will say, **"Removed [fruit]"**. :P

Please check working example at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/acuke3/3)

Answer (score 0):

1. Checkboxes are independent of submit buttons. Just write the checkboxes w/o the submit button and you'll have checkboxes w/o a submit button. :)
2. As far as the page "reloading", use JS or a JS framework of your choice (such as jQuery, MooTools, etc) to show the appropriate words on checkbox click.

Let us know if you need more details.

Comment: I know that Checkboxes don't always need submit buttons! :) What I want is that every selection should be displayed as an echo statement without needing to click "submit"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the whole page to reload and still by dynamic you'll have to use more than just PHP. You can use an AJAX request to send the server information on which checkboxes are checked, and then reply accordingly. An easier/better solution would be just to have the Javascript that would be required for the AJAX request show the Apples/Grapes/Oranges/Mangoes `onclick` rather than submitting the form each time a user changes a checkbox.